# Merge Objects in a JavaScript Array to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js, underscore.js

I am trying to create a single JavaScript object from an array of objects.

Some values in the object remain the same, while the numerical or float values need to be summed up to form the new single object.

How can this be achieved?

```
[{
    'visit_date': '2013-02-02',
    'house_number': '22',
    'price': 12.98,
    'count_value': 21.554,
    'variance': -23.434343434
},
{
    'visit_date': '2013-02-02',
    'house_number': '22',
    'price': 34.78,
    'count_value': 1.34,
    'variance': -23.434343434
},
{
    'visit_date': '2013-02-02',
    'house_number': '22',
    'price': 61.41,
    'count_value':1.94,
    'variance': -12.977677874
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to achieve it

```
var result = a.reduce(function (acc, c) {
    acc.visit_date = c.visit_date;
    acc.house_number = c.house_number;
    acc.price += c.price;
    acc.count_value += c.count_value;
    acc.variance += c.variance;
    return acc;
}, {
    'visit_date': '',
    'house_number': '',
    'price': 0,
    'count_value': 0,
    'variance': 0
});
```

The result will be

```
{
    visit_date: "2013-02-02",
    house_number: "22",
    price: 109.17,
    count_value: 24.834,
    variance: -59.846364742
}
```

Comment: While using reduce is probable the best way, he might have to implement it himself or use a library if this has to be compatible with older browsers.

Comment: It was available in JavaScript 1.8 and the **real browsers** should support it. :)

Comment: Yeah, and really, who cares about the [more than a quarter of the general browsing public](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) who use a browser that doesn't? They should upgrade, clearly. Their own darned fault, really. (I'm just saying, mentioning a shim is free.)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the array, use a `for-in` loop on each object, and for entries where `typeof value === "number"`, sum them up. Presumably do something useful when they aren't numbers, but you haven't said what. :-)

Sorry, missed the jQuery tag. It can be shorter with jQuery's `each`:

```
var dest = {};

$.each(source, function(index, entry) {
    $.each(entry, function(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            dest[key] = key in dest ? dest[key] + value : value;
        }
        else {
            // do something useful with non-numbers
        }
     });
});
```

`each` will loop through the array elements if you give it an array, or through the properties of an object if you give it a non-array object. So in the above, the outer `each` loops through your array, and the inner `each` loops through each object's properties.

The `in` operator on this line:

```
dest[key] = key in dest ? dest[key] + value : value;
```

...tells us whether `dest` already has a key with that name: If so, we *add* the value to it. If not, we create a new property for that key using the value.

---

Original non-jQuery:

*Roughly*:

```
var dest = {};
var entry;
var index;
var key;
var value;

for (index = 0; index < source.length; ++index) {
    entry = source[index];
    for (key in entry) {
        value = entry[key];
        if (typeof value === "number") {
            dest[key] = key in dest ? dest[key] + value : value;
        }
        else {
            // do something useful with non-numbers
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When they are not numerical type.. just assign the distinct value.. i don't still understand you for-in solution.. can you explain a bit more.. Cheers

Comment: More about `for-in`: *[Myths and realities of `for..in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)*

Comment: @kengimel: JavaScript has only one number type: `Number` All numbers are IEEE-754 double-precision floating point, even ones you treat as integers.

Comment: @sza: Not at all, and more general-purpose than having to start with a pre-initialized object. `reduce` just does the same thing under the covers. I'm not saying `reduce` isn't another good option, on ES5-enabled engines or with a shim.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/tQLy5/1/

```
function aToObject(a) {
    var o = {}, l = a.length;
    while (l--) {
        for (key in a[l]) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof (o[key]) === 'number') {
                o[key] += a[l][key];   
            } else {
                 o[key] = a[l][key];   
            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Just iterate over the whole array and then over the properties of the objects in array. If the property is number you add them together, otherwise you just assign the property to the new object.